# How to set margin to zero between views in storyboard Xcode11

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard, xcode11

I have a question while developing iOS application using Xcode11.4.

This is my first time to developing iOS, sorry for my stupidity.
Storyboard development is too hard to me.

[image: the view what I wanna make]
This is what I wanna make.

The way I did is make a stackview and put two textviews in stackview.
And it's not problem so far.

[image]
< My storyboard >

There is vertical margin between textviews, so I tried to set them to zero using View inspector.
[image]

But it is not working, and Xcode displaying constraint error.
Is there any better way to set margin to zero between vertical TextViews?

Thanks.

Comment: Select your stackView & you will see `spacing` attribute in properties, now set its value to zero. [More info](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview/1616225-spacing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your stack view > now select attribute inspector which is showing with blue icon in this image

[image]

now edit spacing as you want

Comment: welcome just remember to play with "Distribution" and "Alignment" attributes next time without zero spacing ,will give you more understanding how stack view works in iOS .